# How can i center this menu?

Tags: html, css

I have this code for my menu
I got some list items i wanna center in the black box.
The 4 Li-items are floating left to get them inside the black box

```css
nav {
  display: block;
  width: 900px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
nav ul {
  width: 900px;
  padding: .7em;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  background: #444;
}
nav li {
  float: left;
}
nav a {
  float: left;
  padding: .8em 1.5em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #555;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  font: bold 1.1em/1'trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #fff #ccc #999 #eee;
  background: #c1c1c1;
  background: linear-gradient(#f5f5f5, #c1c1c1);
}
nav a:hover,
nav a:focus {
  outline: 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  background: #fac754;
  background: linear-gradient(#fac754, #f8ac00);
}
nav a:active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3) inset;
}
nav li:first-child a {
  border-left: 0;
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <div>
      <li><a href='storingsoverzicht.php'>Storingen</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href='Contacten.php'>Contacten</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href='nieuwestoring.php'>Nieuwe Storing</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href='uitloggen.php'>Uitloggen</a>
      </li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I like to have the Li-items centered in the middle of the black box.
How do i do this?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: You can't have a `div` as a direct child of `ul`.

Comment: Try margin:left:auto; margin-right:auto; on your <ul> element

Comment: @Muhammad Usman  Exactly !!

Comment: … and remove the floating (otherwise auto margins won’t work.)

Comment: @MathieuDormeval  already tried :/

Comment: @JelleBotman  Have a look my answer.

Comment: why -3 vote???  i did my best guys

Comment: Again: ***This is invalid HTML.*** You **can't** have a `div` as a direct child of `ul` - only `li` allowed.

Comment: @JelleBotman, I edited your question to fix wrong markup. that's the reason people were giving wrong vote.

Comment: Guys, he is pretty new here, may be he is also new in html,css why did you give negative vote, from my point of view you should give negative vote

Comment: Edit rolled back, please do not edit OP code if it is wrong, that's the point of the question. If the code is wrong, answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `float` from `ul` and `li` and add `display: inline-block;` and for parent `nav` add `text-align: center;` I just corrected css, have a look:

```css
nav {
  display: block;
  width: 900px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
nav ul {
  width: 900px;
  padding: .7em;
  margin: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  background: #444;
  font-size: 0;
}
nav li {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
}
nav a {
  float: left;
  padding: .8em 1.5em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #555;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  font: bold 1.1em/1'trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #fff #ccc #999 #eee;
  background: #c1c1c1;
  background: linear-gradient(#f5f5f5, #c1c1c1);
}
nav a:hover,
nav a:focus {
  outline: 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  background: #fac754;
  background: linear-gradient(#fac754, #f8ac00);
}
nav a:active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3) inset;
}
nav li:first-child a {
  border-left: 0;
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
      <li><a href='storingsoverzicht.php'>Storingen</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href='Contacten.php'>Contacten</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href='nieuwestoring.php'>Nieuwe Storing</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href='uitloggen.php'>Uitloggen</a>
      </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: ***This is invalid HTML.*** You **can't** have a `div` as a direct child of `ul` - only `li` allowed.

Comment: @JelleBotman, please accept the answer to help others. Also notice that, I removed wrong markup so you can copy my html as well.

Comment: @connexo I fixed the html sorry, I did not notice it before.

Comment: Now fix the `inline-block` whitespace issue (you will have noted the additional 4px horizontal space between the list items, that is whitespace). Set `ul { font-size: 0; }` and re-set the correct `font-size` for the  `li`.

Comment: I fixed it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Though your HTML is invalid, since you should not have a `div` inside you r `ul, Just make the following changes/addition to your css.

Demo : http://jsbin.com/quluhevibe/edit?output

```
    nav ul {
      width: 900px;
      padding: .7em;
      float: left;
      margin: 0px;
      list-style: none;
      background: #444;
      text-align: center;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

   nav ul div {
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

Comment: ***You are using invalid HTML.*** You **can't** have a `div` as a direct child of `ul` - only `li` allowed.